Error creating program: TypeError: Expected Buffer
Page.tsx
"use client";
import { useEffect } from "react";

import { WalletMultiButton } from "@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui";
import idl from '@/app/idl/idl.json';
import { PublicKey } from '@solana/web3.js';
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { useAnchorProvider } from "./solana/solana-provider";

const PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey(idl.metadata.address);

export default function Home() {
  const provider = useAnchorProvider();
  console.log('Provider:', provider);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (provider && idl) {
      try {
        const program = new Program(idl, provider);
        console.log('Program:', program);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error creating program:', error);
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Provider or IDL is undefined');
    }
  }, [provider]);

  return (
    <main className="flex items-center justify-center min-h-screen">
      <div className="border hover:border-slate-900 rounded">
        <WalletMultiButton />
      </div>
    </main>
  );
}

solana-provider.tsx
'use client';

import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { AnchorProvider } from '@coral-xyz/anchor';
import { WalletError } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-base';
import {
  AnchorWallet,
  useConnection,
  useWallet,
  ConnectionProvider,
  WalletProvider,
} from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react';
import { WalletModalProvider } from '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui';
import { ReactNode, useCallback, useMemo } from 'react';

import '@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui/styles.css';

export const WalletButton = dynamic(
  async () =>
    (await import('@solana/wallet-adapter-react-ui')).WalletMultiButton,
  { ssr: false }
);

export function SolanaProvider({ children }: { children: ReactNode }) {
  const endpoint = "https://api.devnet.solana.com";
  const onError = useCallback((error: WalletError) => {
    console.error(error);
  }, []);

  return (
    <ConnectionProvider endpoint={endpoint}>
      <WalletProvider wallets={[]} onError={onError} autoConnect={true}>
        <WalletModalProvider>{children}</WalletModalProvider>
      </WalletProvider>
    </ConnectionProvider>
  );
}

export function useAnchorProvider() {
  const { connection } = useConnection();
  const wallet = useWallet();

  return new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet as AnchorWallet, {
    commitment: 'confirmed',
  });
}


Console log
page.tsx:24 Error creating program: TypeError: Expected Buffer
    at captureStackTrace (capture-stack-trace.ts:3:21)
    at console.error (intercept-console-error.ts:35:28)
    at Home.useEffect (page.tsx:24:17)

What Could be the issue? every example uses this structure but noone else gets expected buffer error

You might need to use the useAnchorWallet instead of useWallet hook when instantiating the AnchorProvider
const wallet = useAnchorWallet()

AnchorProvider(
    connection,
    wallet,
    AnchorProvider.defaultOptions()
);

